# How can i save table changed ? the entry wasn't amended and keep on resetting to blank table

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Hello i am relatively new to programming and coding, i couldnt figured out how to save the data entered from the form to tabledataadapter (data binding source) . i  wanted  to create a  table form that could save / edit / remove . followed multiple guides but none worked out . it is mentioned "Data Saved" but i couldnt located the files or save it in the form

edit :

[this is what it shows after saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KNA3.png)

[when i returned to designing mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/716UU.png)

and it resets everytime i reboot the program. all the record were missing both from the Form as well as from the database.

is it because of the connection is not being set ? (i am using datasourcebinding) or is there any other solution that i could opt to .

Sorry for the bad grammar , english isnt my native language.

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        Try
            Me.Validate()

            Me.JobStatusBindingSource.EndEdit()


            Dim orderdelete As JobStatusDataSet.Job_StatusDataTable = CType(JobStatusDataSet.Job_Status.GetChanges(Data.DataRowState.Deleted), JobStatusDataSet.Job_StatusDataTable)

            Dim ordernew As JobStatusDataSet.Job_StatusDataTable = CType(JobStatusDataSet.Job_Status.GetChanges(Data.DataRowState.Added), JobStatusDataSet.Job_StatusDataTable)

            Dim ordermodified As JobStatusDataSet.Job_StatusDataTable = CType(JobStatusDataSet.Job_Status.GetChanges(Data.DataRowState.Modified), JobStatusDataSet.Job_StatusDataTable)


            Try
                If Not orderdelete Is Nothing Then
                    Job_StatusTableAdapter.Update(orderdelete)

                End If

                If Not ordernew Is Nothing Then
                    Job_StatusTableAdapter.Update(ordernew)

                End If

                If Not ordermodified Is Nothing Then
                    Job_StatusTableAdapter.Update(ordermodified)

                End If

                JobStatusDataSet.AcceptChanges()

            Catch ex As Exception

            Finally
                If Not orderdelete Is Nothing Then
                    orderdelete.Dispose()

                End If
                If Not ordernew Is Nothing Then
                    ordernew.Dispose()

                End If
                If Not ordermodified Is Nothing Then
                    ordermodified.Dispose()


                End If
            End Try
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Saving Error")
        End Try



    End Sub
```

Edit 2 :

after manually inserting data thru the original access database , finally i could [preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfRu3.png) the data .. but it is not shown on the table[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1hvL.png) . this has been going on for me since last week.

Comment: Don't use an empty catch block `Catch ex As Exception`.  So comment that out because for now, you want to know any exception that is thrown.

Comment: well after amending changes as you asked for , there is an Error or 

System.InvalidOperationException : The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.' 

How do i solve this ?

Comment: i encountered this a lot tbh, couldnt resolved this matter as more connection sometimes become null and etc.

Comment: The error you're getting is just that.  You've not got the correct ole drivers for your version of access installed.  Remember that 32bit vs 64bit matters.

Comment: i already have x64 driver installed and debuged on the same version, the error doesnt appear any longer but still doesnt save and i couldnt retrieve previous data entered to the table and its kept on losing it each time i reboot the application form

Comment: Are you running your app 64bit?  That will need to match your driver.  But if you're certain that issue has been resolved, would think you would be getting a different exception now?

Comment: Check what value is returned by those `Update` calls. If the call returns at all then the result will be either zero or non-zero. If it's zero then there were no changes to save in the first place and if it's non-zero then there were changes and they were saved. If you're using Access, there's every chance that you're just overwriting the changes with a clean database every time you build.

Comment: apparently after i ran debug on x64 , there is no error pops up . but the data remained the same as the beginning it kept on showing empty table each time i end the debug process.

Comment: You are looking at the design view of your form.  Data usually isn't loaded until the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the database is local, that is, it is created through Visual Studio itself. In this case, every time the application is recompiled, it erases the existing Database and creates a new one. You can do a simple test as follows:

1. Compile the application normally and add some data
2. Close the application.
3. Open the file explorer and navigate to the /bin/debug project
   folder
4. Open the application through your project's .exe executable file

That way the program is not recompiled and therefore the database is not recreated. Previously saved data should appear. In this case, in the final application, each copy of the application would have its own database.

You can create a database using SQL SERVER and SQL MANAGEMENT STUDIO and in Visual Studio just connect your application to the database, this way it would not be deleted at each recompilation and in the final application all copies would use the same database.